# Autofocus for video capture in OpenCV4Android 2.4.3

Tags: android, video, opencv, camera, autofocus

I have a problem with auto focus while taking a video with android `opencv`. I found a lot of solution suggest me to use `mCamera`. However It is used only for taking photos. Are there any function in `OpenCV` to set video capture to be in autofocus mode.

Another thing is I use `opencv4android` tutorial 4 as my base code. The code uses `mOpenCvCameraView` object to control `camera` and view. Can anybody suggest me how to get `mCamera` or `VideoCapture` object and set parameters by myself

Comment: I found org.opencv.highgui.Highgui.java. There is a constant called CV_CAP_ANDROID_FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO However i dont know how can i set this to mOpenCvCameraView.

Comment: I found this http://developer.android.com/reference/android/hardware/Camera.Parameters.html#FOCUS_MODE_CONTINUOUS_VIDEO ...  trying to integrate with my opencv

Comment: may be this current opencv doesnt support autofocus on VideoCapture
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-opencv/BhDSI-2IzP8  isnt it?????